# finding log likelihood data using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, log-likelihood

I am trying to use numpy to get the log likelihood for native bayes
The following is the probability of getting 1 in each dimension when label is +1 and -1 repectively:

```
positive = [0.07973422 0.02657807]
negative = [0.04651163 0.02491694] #both of these have the dimension d
```

the following are the test and label for the test

```
x = np.array([[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]) # dimension is n*d : note that the d is same as above
y = np.array([-1,1,-1]) #dimension is n
```

#result that I want

```
result = [-3.73983529 -2.55599409 -6.76026018] #dimension is n
```

logic->
each result element corresponds to a row in x which depends on what value of y to use to use the positive and negative

i.e.: for row 0, i.e. [0,1], the label -1, that means we take the posprob.

```
-3.73983529 = log( 1 - 0.04651163 ) + log(0.02491694)
```

, here we are subtracting from 1 because the probability of 0 is 1 minus probability of 1.

I am using tight loops right now. But I want to solve this using numpy methods to make it faster.

Comment: It might help if you would paste add the "tight loops" that you're using now into the body of your question so that we could see them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast everything to `n x d` and then use `np.where`.

```
positive = [0.07973422, 0.02657807]
negative = [0.04651163, 0.02491694]  # both of these have the dimension d

x = np.array(
    [[0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
)  # dimension is n*d : note that the d is same as above
y = np.array([-1, 1, -1])  # dimension is n

d = len(positive)
n = len(x)

# Cast all to n x d

positive = np.array([positive]*n)
negative = np.array([negative]*n)

y = np.repeat(y, d).reshape(n, d)

# Determine whether to use pos or neg probabilities
pos_neg = np.where(y == 1, positive, negative)

# Determine whether to use prob or 1-prob
probs = np.where(x == 0, 1 - pos_neg, pos_neg)

# Take logs and then sum
log_probs = np.log(probs)

log_like = np.sum(log_probs, axis = 1)

print(log_like)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
probs = np.array([negative,positive])[(y+1)//2]
np.log(np.where(x==0, 1 - probs, probs)).sum(1)

array([-3.73983544, -2.55599408, -6.76026028])
```